# How to save the previous result

Tags: java

I have a task

Create a class Math with methods:
int calculate (int a, int b) - the operation itself
and
int returnPrev () - returns the previous calculated result.

Create class Addition to represent addition operations. Override the methods.
I've created abstract class Math

```
    abstract class Math {
        abstract int calculate(int a,int b);
        abstract int returnPrev();
    }


    public class Addition extends Math {
        int result;
        int prevresult;


        @Override
        int calculate(int a, int b) {
           result = a + b;
            return result   }
        @Override
        int returnPrevious() {
         }
    }
```

For me is unclear how should i create a method returnPrevious ?? I do not understand how should i save the first result.

For any explanation would be very grateful

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: Mind showing us your class Addition?

Comment: Today on StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry, using stack for first time, got some problems with saving the question. The output should be like The output should be like:
calculate(1, 2) = 3
calculate(2, 3) = 5
Previous() = 3 /So the question is how to save the result and use it in method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do not use a name which OOTB e.g you should use `MyMath` to avoid conflict with OOTB `Math`.
2. It's better to declare `MyMath` as in `interface`. Note that multiple interfaces can be implemented by a class but only one class can be extended.
3. Assign the value of `result` to `prevresult` before putting the value of new calculation into it.

```
interface MyMath {
    public int calculate(int a, int b);
    public int returnPrev();
}

class Addition implements MyMath {
    int result;
    int prevresult;

    @Override
    public int calculate(int a, int b) {
        prevresult = result;
        result = a + b;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int returnPrev() {
        return prevresult;
    }
}

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Addition addition = new Addition();
        System.out.println(addition.calculate(10, 20));
        System.out.println(addition.returnPrev());
        System.out.println(addition.calculate(20, 30));
        System.out.println(addition.returnPrev());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
30
0
50
30
```

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Addition extends Math {
    int result;
    int prevresult;


    @Override
    int calculate(int a, int b) {
        this.prevresult = result;
        result = a + b;
        return result ;
    }

    @Override
    int returnPrev() {
        return this.prevresult;
    }

}
```